# Why is Select Count(*) slower than Select * in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

When i am running queries in `VirtualBox Sandbox` with hive. I feel `Select count(*)` is too much slower than the `Select *`.

Can anyone explain what is going on behind?

And why this delay is happening?

Answer (score 14):

```
select * from table
```

It can be a Map only job But

```
Select Count(*) from table
```

It can be a Map and Reduce job

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thanks , Can u explain me how its code behind working? Is it any way for getting execution time? What is MY JOB meaned?

Answer (score 4):

There are three types of operations that a hive query can perform.

In order of cheapest and fastest to more expensive and slower here they are.

A hive query can be a metadata only request.

Show tables, describe table are examples. In these queries the hive process performs a lookup in the metadata server. The metadata server is a SQL database, probably MySQL, but the actual DB is configurable.

A hive query can be an hdfs get request.
Select * from table, would be an example. In this case hive can return the results by performing an hdfs operation. hadoop fs -get, more or less.

A hive query can be a Map Reduce job.

Hive has to ship the jar to hdfs, the jobtracker queues the tasks, the tasktracker execute the tasks, the final data is put into hdfs or shipped to the client.

The Map Reduce job has different possibilities as well.

It can be a Map only job.
Select * from table where id > 100 , for example all of that logic can be applied on the mapper.

It can be a Map and Reduce job,
Select min(id) from table;
Select * from table order by id ;

It can also lead to multiple map Reduce passes, but I think the above summarizes some behaviors.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the DB is using clustered primary keys so the query searches each row for the key individually, row by agonizing row, not from an index.

- Run `optimize table`. This will ensure that the data pages are
  physically stored in sorted order. This could conceivably speed up a
  range scan on a clustered primary key.
- create an additional non-primary index on just the change_event_id
  column. This will store a copy of that column in index pages which be
  much faster to scan. After creating it, check the explain plan to
  make sure it's using the new index

Comment: Something tells me that AlexHenderson_v1.00 was answering the wrong question.

Comment: Nope. The comment must have been edited after my response. Something tells me you spelt my name wrong.