# Why does YARN takes a lot of memory for a simple count operation?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a standard configured HDP 2.2 environment with Hive, HBase and YARN.

I've used Hive (/w HBase) to perform a simple count operation on a table that has about 10 million rows and it resulted with a 10gb of memory consumption from YARN.

How can I reduce this memory consumption? Why does it need so much memory just to count rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple count operation involves a map reduce job at the back end. And that involves 10 million rows in your case. Look [here](http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/why-is-select-count-slower-than-select/) for a better explanation. Well this is just for the things happening at the background and execution time and not your question regarding memory requirements. Atleast, it will give you a heads up for the places to look for. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060630/why-is-select-count-slower-than-select-in-hive) has few solutions to speed up as well. Happy coding